# Method error "Cannot find Symbol": Only one method is giving this error(finalResults)

Tags: java

So, this program is meant to play a game like rock, paper, scissors. It is called Monkey, Robot, Pirate, Ninja, Zombie. Every method that I call upon works, except for the method "finalResults". I have called upon finalResults just like every other method, but the variables in the parentheses when I call upon finalResults are underlined red and give the error "Cannot find symbol". All of these methods are in the same class, so I am confused as to what I am doing wrong. Thanks guys!

```
    package project4;

    import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 *
 * @author seanchalant
 */
public class Project4 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner in
            for (int Round = 1; Round<=5; Round++)//for loop for the 5 rounds
            {     
                System.out.println("Round# "+Round +"\n");//print statement for number of round using 'for loop'
                System.out.println("Please enter a number from 1-5:");
                int PlayerChoice = in.nextInt();
                int ComputerChoice = (int)(Math.random()*5) + 1;
                while (ComputerChoice==PlayerChoice)
                {
                    System.out.println("There is a tie! Please enter a new choice (1-5):");
                    PlayerChoice = in.nextInt();
                    ComputerChoice = (int)(Math.random()*5) +1;
                }
                convertChoice(PlayerChoice);
                determineWinner(PlayerChoice, ComputerChoice);

            }
      finalResults(PlayerWin, ComputerWin, user, computer); *ERROR IS HERE*
    }

    public enum PlayerChoice {Monkey, Robot, Pirate, Ninja, Zombie};
    public static PlayerChoice convertChoice(int PlayerChoice)
    {

                switch (PlayerChoice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return Project4.PlayerChoice.Monkey;
                    case 2:
                        return Project4.PlayerChoice.Robot;
                    case 3:
                        return Project4.PlayerChoice.Pirate;
                    case 4:
                        return Project4.PlayerChoice.Ninja;
                    case 5:
                        return Project4.PlayerChoice.Zombie;    
                }
                return null;

    }
    public static PlayerChoice determineWinner(int PlayerChoice, int ComputerChoice)
    {       
        int round = 0;
        int PlayerWin = 0;
        int ComputerWin = 0;        
        if (PlayerChoice==1 && ComputerChoice==2)//if statements for the different scenarios. 
            {
                System.out.println("Monkey annoys robot enough to cause malfunction. Player wins!");
                PlayerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==1 && ComputerChoice==3)
            {
                System.out.println ("Pirate shoots monkey in the face. Computer wins!");
                ComputerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==1 && ComputerChoice==4)
            {
                System.out.println ("Monkey embraces it's inner ninja and wins? Player wins?");
                PlayerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==1 && ComputerChoice==5)
            {
                System.out.println ("Zombie uses monkey for sustenance. Computer wins!");
                ComputerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==2 && ComputerChoice==1)
            {
                System.out.println ("Monkey annoys robot enough to cause malfunction. Computer Wins!");
                ComputerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==2 && ComputerChoice ==3)
            {
                System.out.println ("Pirate pours rum down robot's throat. It breaks. Computer Wins!");
                ComputerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==2 && ComputerChoice==4)
            {
                System.out.println ("Ninja gets decapitated by lasers. Player wins!");
                PlayerWin++; 
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==2 && ComputerChoice==5)
            {
                System.out.println ("Zombie gets decapitated by lasers. Player wins!");
                PlayerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==3 && ComputerChoice==1)
            {
                System.out.println ("Pirate shoots monkey in the face. Player wins!");
                PlayerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==3 && ComputerChoice==2)
            {
                System.out.println ("Pirate pours rum down robot's throat. It breaks. Player Wins!");
                PlayerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==3 && ComputerChoice==4)
            {
                System.out.println ("Ninja poisons pirate with blowdart. Computer wins!");
                ComputerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==3 && ComputerChoice==5)
            {
                System.out.println ("Zombie uses pirate for sustenance. Computer wins!");
                ComputerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==4 && ComputerChoice==1)
            {
                System.out.println ("Monkey embraces its inner ninja and wins? Computer wins?");
                ComputerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==4 && ComputerChoice==2)
            {
                System.out.println ("Ninja gets decapitated by lasers. Player wins!");
                ComputerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==4 && ComputerChoice==3)
            {
                System.out.println ("Ninja poisons pirate with blowdart. Player wins!");
                PlayerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==4 && ComputerChoice==5)
            {
                System.out.println ("Ninja laughs at slow zombie and decapitates it. Player Wins!");
                PlayerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==5 && ComputerChoice==1)
            {
                System.out.println ("Zombie uses monkey for sustenance. Player wins!");
                PlayerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==5 && ComputerChoice==2)
            {
                System.out.println ("Zombie gets decapitated by lasers. Computer wins!");
                ComputerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==5 && ComputerChoice==3)
            {
                System.out.println ("Zombie uses pirate for sustenance. Player wins!");
                PlayerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerChoice==5 && ComputerChoice==4)
            {
                System.out.println ("Ninja laughs at slow zombie and decapitates it. Computer Wins!");
                ComputerWin++;
                round++;
            }
            if (PlayerWin==PlayerWin+1)
            {
                int[]user = new int [round];
            }
            if (ComputerWin==ComputerWin+1)
            {
                int[]computer = new int[round];
            }
          return null; 
    }
    public static PlayerChoice finalResults(int PlayerWin, int ComputerWin, int[] user, int[] computer)
    {
            System.out.println("Final Results:\n");
            if (PlayerWin==1)
            {
                System.out.println("The player won round "+user[1]+".\n");
            }
            if (PlayerWin==2)
            {
                System.out.println("The player won rounds "+user[1]+" and "+user[2]+".\n");
            }
            if (PlayerWin==3)
            {
                System.out.println("The player won rounds "+user[1]+", "+user[2]+", "+user[3]+".\n");
            }
            if (PlayerWin==4)
            {
                System.out.println("The player won rounds "+user[1]+", "+user[2]+", "+user[3]+", "+user[4]+".\n");

            }
            if (PlayerWin==5)
            {
                System.out.println("The player won rounds "+user[1]+", "+user[2]+", "+user[3]+", "+user[4]+", "+user[5]+".\n");
            }
            if (ComputerWin==1)
            {
                System.out.println("The computer won round "+computer[1]+".\n");
            }
            if (ComputerWin==2)
            {
                System.out.println("The computer won rounds "+computer[1]+" and "+computer[2]+".\n");
            }
            if (ComputerWin==3)
            {
                System.out.println("The computer won rounds "+computer[1]+", "+computer[2]+", "+computer[3]+".\n");
            }
            if (ComputerWin==4)
            {
                System.out.println("The computer won rounds "+computer[1]+", "+computer[2]+", "+computer[3]+", "+computer[4]+".\n");

            }
            if (ComputerWin==5)
            {
                System.out.println("The computer won rounds "+computer[1]+", "+computer[2]+", "+computer[3]+", "+computer[4]+", "+computer[5]+".\n");
            }
            System.out.println("You won a total of "+PlayerWin+"\n");
            System.out.println("The computer won a total of "+ComputerWin+"\n");
             if (PlayerWin>ComputerWin)
            {
                System.out.println("You win the game!\n");
            }
            if (ComputerWin>PlayerWin)
            {
                System.out.println("Computer wins the game!\n");
            }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create them before using them

Comment: They are all already created. PlayerWin, ComputerWin, []user, and []computer were created in the determineWinner method. I then called upon PlayerWin and ComputerWin in the finalResults method

Comment: @sam You mean they are?

Comment: If you are creating them in determineWinner, you cannot use them in main method because they are out of scope. Thanks @eush77

Comment: @sam There is also the edit button :)

Comment: @eush77 I couldn't edit. I believe after few minutes, you cannot edit the comments

Comment: @sam Oh, yes. Excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Create your variables outside of your for loop or/and give them a value:

```
int PlayerWin;
int ComputerWin;
int[] user;
int[] computer;

       for (int Round = 1; Round<=5; Round++)//for loop for the 5 rounds
        {     
            System.out.println("Round# "+Round +"\n");//print statement for number of round using 'for loop'
            System.out.println("Please enter a number from 1-5:");
            PlayerChoice = in.nextInt();
            ComputerChoice = (int)(Math.random()*5) + 1;
            while (ComputerChoice==PlayerChoice)
            {
                System.out.println("There is a tie! Please enter a new choice (1-5):");
                PlayerChoice = in.nextInt();
                ComputerChoice = (int)(Math.random()*5) +1;
            }
            convertChoice(PlayerChoice);
            determineWinner(PlayerChoice, ComputerChoice);

        }
finalResults(PlayerWin, ComputerWin, user, computer);
```

Comment: I am pretty sure they are all already created. PlayerWin, ComputerWin, []user, and []computer were created in the determineWinner method. I then called upon PlayerWin and ComputerWin in the finalResults method.

Comment: @Sean, Yes but they are local variables only accessible in the scope where they've been created so they're not accessible

Comment: But these variables were already created outside of the for loop in a different method 'determineWinner', and then called upon in the 'finalResults' method. I am seriously confused.

Answer (score 0):

The error statement is clear, it means you are using undefined variable :

```
finalResults(PlayerWin, ComputerWin, user, computer);
```

Here you try to use variables that don't exist. Actually, you are trying to use variables that you created in other methods and that are not accessible from the `main` method.

You should consider declaring these variables as class members and not in each method if you want to use them and share them across all methods.

Like :

```
public class Project4 {
    private static int PlayerWin = 0;
    private static int ComputerWin = 0; 
    ...
    // methods
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but now after defining them as their own class members, the values are not carrying over from the other methods and are 0. Any thoughts?